# how to define and use a compile time macro?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to understand more about settings macros for compilation.

The Erlang [compile documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html) shows that a macro can be defined:

> `{d,Macro} {d,Macro,Value}`
>
> ```
> Defines a macro Macro to have the value Value. 
> Macro is of type atom, and Value can be any term. 
> The default Value is true.
> ```

I'm trying to set a macro using a directive:

```
-module(my_mod).    
-compile([debug_info, {d, debug_level, 1}]).
...
```

How would I use this macro in my code? For example I have tried this:

```
my_func() ->
    if 
        debug_level == 1 -> io:format("Warning ...");
        true -> io:format("Error ...")
    end.
```

But 'Error ...' is always output.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a macro in your code using `-define`:

```
-define(debug_level, 1).
```

If you want to be able to override it from the compilation command line, you can wrap it with `-ifndef`:

```
-ifndef(debug_level).
-define(debug_level, 1).
-endif.
```

This way, if you compile with

```
erlc -Ddebug_level=2 file.erl
```

for example, then the macro will have the value 2 instead of the default value 1.

To access the value of a macro, you prepend it with a `?`:

```
my_func() ->
    if
        ?debug_level == 1 -> io:format("Warning ...");
        true -> io:format("Error ...")
    end.
```

Note that since `?debug_level` is a constant, you'll get compiler warnings from the `if` expression about clauses that can never match.

Comment: It seems that the macro cannot be defined as part of the `-compile()` directive.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to define one with `-compile` when you can define one much more clearly and more flexibly using `-define`?